# 500s on fasthosts when trying to install Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

I'm trying to help someone with issues on their fasthosts server. I've downloaded the latest version of Wordpress and uploaded it via FTP. I have enabled PHP 5.4 on the server (it was originally disabled).

However, now whenever I try and do anything, yes ANYTHING, even navigate to the /wp-admin/install.php page I get the following:

```
SERVER ERROR
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

I've been looking at this for a couple of hours now with no luck.
There is no .htaccess yet because the installer hasn't run.
If I add one manually I still get the 500s.

Hoping someone else has had this issue and can help me out.

**EDIT:** The Logs (with IPs and Domain anonymised)

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2014-06-09 17:45:06
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken
2014-06-09 17:45:05 W3SVC1075326405 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET /readme.html - 80 - xxx.xx.xxx.xxx HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/35.0.1916.114+Safari/537.36 - - 200 0 0 7441 464 873
2014-06-09 17:45:06 W3SVC1075326405 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET /wp-admin/css/install.css ver=20100228 80 - xxx.xx.xxx.xxx HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/35.0.1916.114+Safari/537.36 - http://www.example.co.uk/readme.html 200 0 0 5157 493 78
2014-06-09 17:45:06 W3SVC1075326405 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET /wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.png - 80 - xxx.xx.xxx.xxx HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/35.0.1916.114+Safari/537.36 - http://www.example.co.uk/readme.html 200 0 0 2726 492 62
2014-06-09 17:45:06 W3SVC1075326405 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET /wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.svg ver=20131107 80 - xxx.xx.xxx.xxx HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/35.0.1916.114+Safari/537.36 - http://www.example.co.uk/readme.html 404 3 50 1405 419 296
2014-06-09 17:49:08 W3SVC1075326405 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET /wp-admin/install.php - 80 - xxx.xx.xxx.xxx HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/35.0.1916.114+Safari/537.36 - - 500 0 0 1517 387 171
2014-06-09 17:50:59 W3SVC1075326405 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET /wp-admin/install.php - 80 - xxx.xx.xxx.xxx HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/35.0.1916.114+Safari/537.36 - - 500 0 0 1517 413 62
2014-06-09 17:51:01 W3SVC1075326405 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET /wp-admin/install.php - 80 - xxx.xx.xxx.xxx HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/35.0.1916.114+Safari/537.36 - - 500 0 0 1517 413 62
2014-06-09 17:51:01 W3SVC1075326405 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET /wp-admin/install.php - 80 - xxx.xx.xxx.xxx HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/35.0.1916.114+Safari/537.36 - - 500 0 0 1517 413 46
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: The hosting won't let me access them.

Comment: Are you sure? A lot of hosts create a log directory in the parent of the www folder.

Comment: Hang on I got it, it's just the latest one that wouldn't open... will add above.

Comment: That seems to be just the access log … but what the _error log_ has to say would be of interest here.

Comment: This is the only log I have access to.

Comment: Try Changing directories to 755 and files to 644 recursively.

Comment: Tried updating permissions, it looks like it updated them, but they're still listed in FileZilla as 0700. Even after refreshing the server. :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it working.

A few things first, the fasthosts server my client has is a Windows one. This is why I couldn't update permissions on files and folders. Secondly, I tried switching across to Linux but their control panel kept failing and saying it was unsuccessful.

Anyway, I eventually stumbled onto this help document: https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/1751/related/1

Turns out if you look at `Step 4 (Windows Only)` that you need to download a web config file and stick it in your `htdocs` folder. Once I had that in place the 500s stopped and I could get to the Wordpress install page.